# javascript load javascript and then render header

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 html tags that have 2 addresses in them.  depending on where in the country you are i want the JavaScript to show the address.  I have the API for geolocation figured out.

however the DOM is downloading and AFTER it downloads the JS script runs and by thus showing what you see in the picture.  a few seconds later the right address shows..  obviously I don't want the DOM to be delayed but I need the right address to show.  if I have 20 addresses in 20 `div` elements you can see how unpleasant that can be

I need one address to show depending on IP address;

does anyone know how to fix my JS code

I might be having a problem with the JS line that says

`$(document).ready(function () {`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get("https://geo.ipify.org/api/v1?apiKey=apiKey", function(data) {
    $(".region").each(function() {
      if ($(this).text() != data.location.region) {
        console.log(data.location.region);
        $(this).closest(".m-s-a").hide();
      }
      if ($(this)[0].innerHTML != data.location.region) {
        //  console.log($(this)[0]);
        $(this).closest(".section-cards").hide();
      }
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header th:fragment="header(content)">
  <div class="top-header m-s-a">
    <div class="site-location">
      <div class="site-location_address">
        <a id="location-tx" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/10939+cash,+Dallas,+TX+75247/@32.8059125,-96.8849565,,16z?hl=en" class="site-location-link" target="_blank">
          <span>4908 Cash</span>
          <span>Dallas,&nbsp;</span><span class="region">Texas</span>
          <span>&nbsp;75247</span>
        </a>
        <a class="site-location-tel" href="tel:(214)&nbsp;802-9284">(214) 802-1902</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="top-header m-s-a">
    <div class="site-location">
      <div class="site-location_address">
        <a id="location-mi" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/1216+Southbound+Gratiot+Ave,+Mt+Clemens,+MI+48043/@42.5818175,-82.8853717,17z?hl=en" class="site-location-link" target="_blank">
          <span>1216 Southbound Gratiot Ave,&nbsp;</span>
          <span>Mt. Clemens,&nbsp;</span><span class="region">Michigan</span>
          <span>&nbsp;48043</span>
        </a>
        <a class="site-location-tel" href="tel:(586)&nbsp;738-6223">(586) 738-6223</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <nav th:insert="fragments/nav.html :: nav"></nav>
  <th:block th:replace="${content}" />
</header>
```

[image]

Comment: The delay is simply due to the speed (or lack of) of the geolocation provider. There's nothing you can do as the consumer of the API to correct that. However it's worth noting that making AJAX requests in a loop is not a good idea. If the geolocation service allows you, look to batch up all the addresses in a single request.

Comment: Rather than hide everything with javascript, hide it with css. Then use the javascript to show what you want to show after the page renders.

Comment: Rob can you show me how please

Comment: this is the only fix i could think of  .........                
 if ($(this).text() == data.location.region) {
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            $("div").removeClass("hidden");
                        });
                    }